# MSChart X-Axis displaying even numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have an MSChart displaying data but noticed that my X-axis is displaying even numbers (i.e. 2,4,6,8) rather than all of them (i.e.1,2,3,4,5,6) etc

anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Area axis interval to 1 should fix the problem for you. You can set things programatically as well:

```
        Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: i have tried this but with no success, is there anyway else this could be set? in the properties somewhere?

Comment: That is the property where it's set but make sure you are setting the interval on the correct chart area

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to your ChartArea using the index also. So try the following:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum =0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum =10;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Hope this helps you!